# Redirected to piratenpartji.nl. What can I do?

Tags: google-chrome, redirection, certificate

a few hours ago, I found a link to Kickass Torrent, which is blocked in my country, Italy and went for it. The link worked just fine but wasn't able to save anything. I renounced and continued normal navigation.

I then noticed that everytime I try to access some pages, for instance google.com (but not Google.it) I receive a warning from Chrome that I'm being redirected through piratenpartji.nl

Since I found a similar topic here on 'superuser' I tried what was proposed in the solution, namely shutting down adblock and trying again or trying Incognito mode. Nevertheless, no result.

I performed a search with both Avira and Spybot SD but except for a couple cookies from other origin nothing came up.

What do you suggest I do?

Thanks in advance, feel free to ask any info that might be necessary

Luke

Answer (score 0):

I would greatly suggest you file a bug report on Google Chrome. Also, download another secure browser such as Firefox, and see if it complains. If it doesn't, then it is possible that Chrome as a security flaw.

But be sure to file a bug. This could be pretty bad, although at the moment it might not be.

Comment: Filed the bug report. Also tried on Firefox, but nothing good, same problem: SSL certificate. Just to inquiry more I tried to connect via Playstation 3 browser: as long as I simply used it online, no problem, when I tried to access Google.com even there it warned me of discrepancies in the certificate.

Would it be possible that somehow this thing changed settings inside my router?

Comment: It's highly unlikely, but it is possible. This is an odd issue. You really should contact Google directly, just to make sure.